# .NET Repeater update with JQuery

Tags: jquery, .net

I managed to update my repeater based on a dropdown change using the onItemChanged value in a DropDownList control.

Now I would like to use JQuery to do the same thing but without a complete page refresh.

Can anyone point me in the rifht direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an updatePanel to refresh specific parts of a page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

You can then use a client side script to add a "loading" graphic to make it obvious that a part of the page is refreshing its content.

Comment: Update panel has been around since .Net 3.5It's not .Net4 specific. Please edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to call page methods asynchronously. google `jquery.ajax asp.net` or `jquery.ajax asp.net repeater` and you'll get dozens of samples.
UPDATE: Also, check out [this great tutorial](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jQuery/jQueryPart2.aspx#FirstStepsAjax) from Rick Strahl about using ajax methods in jQuery.

Comment: @Sean McMillan: Completely disagree. When google provides useful results in its first page, it *is* helpful! + Didn't you see the jQuery.ajax part?!